# Empty result for Doctrine using Entity and Repository folder - migration from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm working in app upgrade from symfony 3.4 to 4.4.

But I'm having an issue with the query selects, I'm not sure why the result is always empty:

```
        return $this
            ->_em
            ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM App\Entity\InternalUsers u')
            ->getResult();

Result: Array ( )
```

Using with getRepository:

```
        $user = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(InternalUsers::class)
            ->validate($this->_getFilterParams(), $this->getParameter('ENCRYPTION_KEY'));
        print_r($user);

Result: Array ( )

 Validate function is inside InternalUserRepository
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use CoreBundle\DoctrineExtensions\Paginate\Paginate;
use CoreBundle\Utils\Validate;
use App\Repository\BaseRepository;
use App\Entity\InternalUsers;

use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

/**
 * Internal Users
 * Controls DB operations of internal users.
 */
class InternalUserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {
    /**
     *
     * @var type 
     */
    protected $InternalUsers;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry) {
        parent::__construct($registry, InternalUsers::class);
    }

    /**
     * Validate credentias.
     *
     * @param array  $userData      User creteria.
     * @param string $encryptionKey Entrypt key.
     *
     * @return type
     */
    public function validate(array $userData, string $encryptionKey) {
        $criteria = [
            'username'    => $userData['username'],
            'password'    => sha1($encryptionKey . $userData['password'])
        ];

        $user   = $this->findOneBy($criteria);   
        var_dump($user); // NULL
        if ($user) {                        
            return $user;
        }        
    }
```

It's using my cli:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:query:dql "SELECT cat FROM App\Entity\InternalUsers cat"

 array(0) {
}
```

I've a supposition with the ORM manually adjusted:

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    # alias: App
        #            AppBundle:
        #                is_bundle: false
        #                type: annotation
        #                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
        #                prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
        #                alias: AppBundle
                    App\Entity\:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\'
                        alias: App\Entity\
```

But I'm still not getting results, I've almost 2 days working on this issue and there is no answer after investigating and reading the documentations.

It was another try, but there were no results as well.

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: 'service'
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: 'service'
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: 'service'
                    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                          STRING_AGG: GalleryCore\CoreBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DQL\StringAgg
```

Answer (score 2):

Here an update!

It looks like related to type of Entity mapping.

After configuring the doctrine.orm.

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        #default_entity_manager: default
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        #entity_managers:
            #default:
                #metadata_cache_driver:
                #    type: 'service'
                #    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                #query_cache_driver:
                #    type: 'service'
                #    id: doctrine.cache.memcached
                #dql:
                #    string_functions:
                #          STRING_AGG: GalleryCore\CoreBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DQL\StringAgg
                #connection: default
                #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        mappings:
            # alias: App
#            AppBundle:
#                is_bundle: false
#                type: annotation
#                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
#                prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
#                alias: AppBundle
            #App\Entity:
                #is_bundle: false
                #type: annotation
                #dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                #prefix: 'App\Entity'
                #alias: App
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

I ran this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

to generate the entities correctly in my src/Entity folder
output:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
Importing mapping information from "default" entity manager
  > writing src/Entity/Bonsai.trackSites.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.adTagTypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.albumAssets.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.appUrls.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.adTags.php
  > writing src/Entity/Bonsai.trackAssettypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Bonsai.trackViews.php
  > writing src/Entity/Bonsai.trackVisitors.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.apps.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.adGptTags.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.appConfigurations.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.appFeatures.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.appUrlTypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.assetFlags.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.assetTypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.assetVotes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.assets.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.assetsKeywords.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.exifValues.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.comments.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.exifFields.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.domains.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.countries.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.featuredAssetsData.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.fieldValues.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.jobsQueue.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.regions.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.indexJobs.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.keywords.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.externalValues.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.releaseDates.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.requestTypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.responseLogs.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.userRoles.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.trendingConfiguration.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.votesConfiguration.php
  > writing src/Entity/Bonsai.trackAssets.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.internalUsers.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.commentFlags.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.verticals.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.fields.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.fieldTypes.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.imageTags.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.internalCategories.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.sitesConnections.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.threadAssets.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.trendingCriterias.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.trendingFormulaDetails.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.trendingFormulas.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.userSettings.php
  > writing src/Entity/Gallery.userVariables.php
  > writing src/Entity/AdGptTags.php
```

after made a couple of adjustments:

```
        $user = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(InternalUsers::class)
            ->findOneBy(
                $criteria = [
                    'username' => $this->_getFilterParams()['username'],
                    'password' => sha1($this->getParameter('ENCRYPTION_KEY') . $this->_getFilterParams()['password'])
                ]
            );
            
            // validate($this->_getFilterParams(), $this->getParameter('ENCRYPTION_KEY'));
        var_dump($user->getUsername());
        exit;
```

it's my output:

```
string(10) "superadmin"
```

Comment: Had this issue with a freshly created project on Symfony 6, it couldn't detect any changes until I ran your import command. Thanks!